# How can I map values in a Hash map to a Link List?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I need to count the number of ancestor classes of a class from a given code.

For that I am scanning the code and I was able to find out the classes and whether they extends or not. If the class extends what is the class that extends that class. So, accordingly I am inserting this data in a Hash Map where it contains the class as a key and the class which extends that class as the value. If a class doesn't extends it will contain a empty String (""). So, I need to put these classes into a link list where I can get a full connection of the classes.

As an example, suppose I have following values in the hash map:

```
(A,B) - This means A extends B 
(B,C) - This means B extends C
(D,E)
(E,F)
```

Accordingly, A extends B and B extends C. So, what I need to do is, I need to put this data in a link list so as to see the connection and identify the ancestors.Once these are put in a link list I need them to be in a array list as well.

So it will be like A->B->C (One item in the array list),D->E->F (the other item in the array list).
So, up to now, I store the classes in a Hashmap, I have implemented a Doubly Link List as well. I need to figure out a way to map the data in this Hash Map to a ArrayList containing the Link Lists.
Can anyone please give me any idea on how to do this?

I need to do this in Java. And I have used Eclipse for doing this.

I need to map the Hash Map classes to an Array List containing those Link Lists.

Comment: I see no attempt here, or any *specific* question. What have you tried, and what is stopping you from completing it? --- Please read thru some of the [**Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) articles, e.g. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Right now your question is **too broad**, and reads as a do-the-work-for-me request, and that is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: Why does the A->B->C have to be a `LinkedList`, not some other kind of `List`?

Comment: At that time I was trying to map the data into a Lined List (in order to keep track on the inheritance hierarchy ). But I solved the issue by mapping the Hash Map data into a directed Graph

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there are dozens of possible solutions for your problem. But the one that instantly came to my mind is the graph implementation.

1. Present each pair element from your Hash Map as an elementary graph that includes two nodes with a peculiar value and one edge that connects them.
2. Using any of well-known algorithms, run through every graph and in case of the node's value match - just combine those graphs into the new one, including duplicate node merging.
3. All-in-all, after all the created graphs are marked as "visited" - add all the values into unique Linked List for each of the graphs.

Comment: thanks for the idea I mapped the data in the Hash Map to a Graph and solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

A tree seems like a more natural data structure to store this data because of the hierarchical nature of classes. A tree also lends itself to being able to inspect ancestors/descendants.

Comment: Why would a `TreeMap` be better than a `HashMap`? --- Also, you're supposed to be answering, not asking another question. If you have a question for OP, write a comment.